# Reachability of Matera in late December/early January

Tags: public-transport, italy

We are considering traveling to [Matera, Italy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matera), from late December (between Christmas and New Year's Eve) to early January.

If we fly to [Bari (IATA airport code `BRI`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bari_Karol_Wojty%C5%82a_Airport), is there a chance to find some transport between the airport and Matera (so we do not have to rent a car), or is public transport (including taxis) for that route during that time of the year problematic?

Comment: Hi, how did it go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bus between Bari Airport and Matera. According to the [journey planner](http://www.aeroportidipuglia.it/bus-pugliairbus-), it should take around 75 minutes.

As you can see from the following example, there seems to be no particular problem with the period which you specify.

[image]

[image]

There are also more departures than this (including later in the day). I'd advise you to use the [journey planner](http://www.aeroportidipuglia.it/bus-pugliairbus-) yourself.

The site defaults to Italian language, but you can change it to English.

[image]